# Cat output from a file and replace words with sed one at a time

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

Im quite new to this, so thank you for being patient

I have got a text file with hundreds of values in it, from which I'd like to populate a ldif template. so for example the file example1.txt has

```
**Consumer1**

**Consumer2**
```

and ldif.txt has

```
***dn: ,cn=Insert,o=Insert
uid:
userPassword:
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
businessCategory:
sn:
cn:***

***dn: ,cn=Insert,o=Insert
uid:
userPassword:
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
businessCategory:
sn:
cn:***
```

For this example Id like to loop through example1.txt and sed so that the first time it encounters "dn:" it substitutes it for "dn:consumer1" then the second "dn:consumer2" and so on, so i would like it to look like this afterwards

```
*dn:**consumer1** ,cn=Insert,o=Insert
uid:
userPassword:
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
businessCategory:
sn:
cn:*

*dn:**consumer2** ,cn=Insert,o=Insert
uid:
userPassword:
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
businessCategory:
sn:
cn:*
```

I have tried this but it just loops through the file and replaces all entries with dn:consumer2 rather than 1, than 2.

```
for i in `cat example1.txt`
do
sed "s/dn:/dn: $i/" ldif.txt > hello.txt
done
```

this outputs the following

```
*dn:**consumer2** ,cn=Insert,o=Insert
uid:
userPassword:
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
businessCategory:
sn:
cn:*

*dn:**consumer2** ,cn=Insert,o=Insert
uid:
userPassword:
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
businessCategory:
sn:
cn:*
```

is there any way of doing it so that it loops through incrementally and replaces back and forth, so that we get the first hit on `dn:consumer1, 2nd hit dn:consumer2` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}$1=="***dn:"{$1="*dn:"a[++k]}1' example1.txt ldif.txt 
*dn:**Consumer1** ,cn=Insert,o=Insert
uid:
userPassword:
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
businessCategory:
sn:
cn:***

*dn:**Consumer2** ,cn=Insert,o=Insert
uid:
userPassword:
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
businessCategory:
sn:
cn:***
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I am getting syntax errors when running it

awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}$1=="***dn:"{$1="*dn:"a[++k]}1' example1.txt ldif2.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Is there a way of running awk so that it debugs it?

Comment: Strange. It runs on my system. Try to break each command in different lines, maybe we can find what is causing the trouble

Comment: Aha! I was running it in Solaris and the awk on it apparently couldn't handle it - I've tried it on AIX and it worked fine - Thank you very much! @user000001

Comment: The default awk on Solaris is old, broken awk which lives in /usr/bin. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead (or even better install gawk).